# Posting question & answer, why must I wait two days to accept it?

Tags: support, questions, answers, accepted-answer

When posting a question and an answer together (like explained [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)) why must I wait two days to accept the answer?
If I have understood correctly, the Q&A-together format is meant to provide knowledge to others and to act as a future reference for a problem that I've managed to solve by myself, so why can't I accept my own answer (which I know to work) immediately?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This encourages others to post alternative solutions (or at least doesn't discourage them like an already accepted answer would). [Source](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/):

> 1. **Wait 48 hours.** You must wait 2 days from the time you originally asked your question before you can accept your own answer. This gives other users a chance to answer the question in good faith, and earn the accepted answer.

As an example, check out [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/336275/find-out-if-user-name-exists) I answered myself. While I had a "solution", the other answers are clearly better.

And it's not like it's a problem either, especially now that the *accept rate* is no longer shown. Just come back after a few days and accept the best answer.

Comment: *This encourages others to post alternative solutions (or at least doesn't discourage them as an already accepted answer would).*  I wasn't thinking about that, but I understand it. Thanks for your explanation.